# How to get SpEL (spring-el) default to null expression working in the Spring XML?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

#### Desired Result:

If the property key is not found, or the value is blank default to `null`.
I need this to be null-able or blank-able in order to work in both wallet and direct login environments.

#### Issue:

I'm unable to get the SpEL default-to-null expression to properly parse.
According to the documentation, however, it should work for Spring 3.0.
I suspect that I am missing something in the XML or dependencies, but can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

#### Note:

An alternate approach to SpEL is acceptable, but I don't want to globally allow all properties to be null. (Don't want to set `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders=true`)

#### Attempted fixes:

1. Added the `springframework.org/schema/context` to the bean definition. *No Effect*
2. Tried replacing the initial `$` with a `#`, but that just gets read as a literal string. (

**Spring Version:** 3.0.7.RELEASE
**Java Version:** 1.6 (*Don't judge, not my choice*)

#### Exception:

```
2018-02-27 11:13:52,982  FATAL class BatchDriver 166 - Server(): Unexpected exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [databaseContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.credu:#{null'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:268)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:362)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    ...
```

#### databaseContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" scope="singleton">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/jdbc.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:/javadriver.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName"><value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value></property>
        <property name="url"><value>${jdbc.url}</value></property>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.credu:#{null}}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.credp:#{null}}"/>
        ~~~ Other Settings ~~~
    </bean>
```

#### jdbc.properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:oci:/@WALLET_ALIAS
#jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@255.255.255.255:9999/db_name
#jdbc.credu=username
#jdbc.credp=password
```

Comment: Try to use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Or even better just rely on the `<context:property-placeholder>`

Comment: `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` doesn't exist in Spring 3.0

Comment: Using <context:property-placeholder/> made no difference.

Comment: OK-OK. I got it. I'm wrong - agreed.

Comment: Turns out that the root cause was that there was a Spring 2.0 dependency that was screwing things up. After updating that to 3.0.7, and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpEL is resolved after placeholders; try something like

```
#{'${jdbc.credu:xxx}' == 'xxx' ? null : '${jdbc.credu:xxx}'}
```

**EDIT**

3.0.7 is extremely old release; Spring versions up to 4.3.x work with java 6.

This works fine with at least 3.1.4.RELEASE:

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.example.Foo">
    <property name="foo" value="#{'${foo:bar}' == 'bar' ? null : '${foo:bar}'}"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
public class So49013862Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("foo.xml");
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean("foo"));
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

and

```
null
Foo [foo=null]
```

with

```
public class Foo {

    private String foo;

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo [foo=" + this.foo + "]";
    }

}
```

I don't have the time to test it with 3.0.x.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I use <context:property-placeholder, it says: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.credu:xxx'

Comment: Turns out the root issue was actually a rogue spring 2.0 dependency.

Comment: One suggestion: Remove the single quotes from the last part of the ternary operation.

Comment: That won't work, because SpEL will attempt to parse the results of the property placeholder resolution; it has to be a literal.